# Magento 2.0 get product attributes through product id

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I need to get all product attributes through product id. How can i get this ?

Comment: No. This question is for Magento 2. Not for Magento 1.

Comment: @PrincePatel there is difference between Magento1 and Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 You need to put this code in your block file of your custom module

**File Path: app/code/Sample/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php**

```
<?php
namespace Sample\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }
}
?>
```

Step 2: then You need to call This in your template Phtml file

```
<?php 
$id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$_product = $block->getProductById($id);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
    echo $attribute->getAttributeCode(); echo '<br />';
    echo $attribute->getStoreLabel(); echo '<br />';
    echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel(); echo '<br />';    
    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); echo '<br />';

    // you might not get value for all attributes
    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); echo '<br />';    
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Pranay, Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::getProductById(). please check once, thanks for your reply...

Comment: @Pranay K ,  I have used this second step code in file where i got product id but not get any output which you have print inside a loop.